# Can't play any video online

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean

I can't play any video online, not on YouTube or Chrome or stream via VLC player. But when try to play video which I have on phone it's ok. Also if I scrol to video on Instagram app freezes, same thing with 9gag. Does anyone have any clue how to solve this, without doing a factory reset? I've allredy tried clearing app cache and clearing cache and dalvik from recovery, I even changed kernel but everything is still same..

Edit: when device is freshly booted I can play videos on YouTube and from storage and Instagram, but when try to play any video in Chrome it becames unresponsive and after that I can't play any video anywhere - app freezes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `hwcomposer` module hangs up. It's internal part of Android, so you should search for newer ROM. [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) are great place for it.

It's common in Cyanogenmod by the way. When CM12 came out for Galaxy S3, it was impossible to play video outside YouTube app.

Another solution is disabling H/W rendering in every app. It depends on the application, but you can do this in for example MX Player and maybe even Chrome (`#disable-webrtc-hw-decoding` from `chrome://flags`)

Comment: I can't use newer ROM on my phone because it'a very old phone, and when try to use LP ROM phone is barely usable. Also I can't disable hw rendering in chrome, can you help me with that, also I can't reach page "chrome://plugins/".

Comment: sorry, my bad, writing at 4 a.m. is not a good idea. I meant `#disable-webrtc-hw-decoding` from `chrome://flags`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it doesn't help a lot. Now I started using stock browser which redirect me to video player apps when try to play video and even that fails somethimes. One thing I don't understand is why problem apeared now, I didn't have any problem untill now.